# Can't connect to my website

Tags: dns

I'm unable to connect to my site http://grantschneider.com (also the site where it is hosted http://2freehosting.com) from my home computer. I'm able to access both from the office, though.

I've tried:

- ipconfig/release+renew+dnsflush
- resetting the router
- tracert (which times out for this site, but not for another site I have hosted at 2freehosting)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try testing it from http://tools.pingdom.com/ and if it works from there, then it's likely your home computer. Windows' dnsflush option does not necessarily guarantee that you clear all the records everywhere, because your ISP probably caches DNS records too. I would suggest waiting a day or so for them to expire.

Comment: @ionFish Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to be working from pingdom. I have been having this issue for a few weeks. Also, I checked my HOST file and it is empty.

Comment: Also, shutting off my firewall did not help.

Comment: @Gschneider have you tried using a private browsing session? Do you have any software on your website blocking you for any reason maybe for too many login attempts? How about from another computer in your home same IP?

Comment: @Anagio Using a private browsing session (hidemyass.com) works for me. (This won't help when I'm trying to connect to the ftp though.) Using another computer in my home does not. No, my site has is mostly text with a few images and a Google ad with no login.

Comment: @Gschneider `hidemyass.com` isn't a "private browsing session" - that's an anonymous proxy. A private browsing session (like "incognito" in Chrome, or "private browsing" in FF) is simply a new browser session that doesn't remember all your cookies/session and history. But you've tried a different computer (and providing that you haven't previously logged into sites on that computer etc.) then that _probably_ rules out your machine. But it is still worth trying a private browser session on your machine.

Comment: @w3d thanks for the clarification, no luck with Chrome Incognito either.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've already tried and the success you see elsewhere and the proxy, I would say that your home ISP is filtering http://2freehosting.com for some reason or another.  Can you switch to OpenDNS or try a different network?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried rebooting your modem as well, or tried connecting directly to your modem instead of through your router? If that doesn't work, you could try using [Google's DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) servers. If it works, you know it's an ISP problem.